# How can I restrict find to only search specific sub-directories?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am using [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) in a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) script. How can I modify that code to include a specific directory under 'bin' , ie './bin/php/' (while still ignoring all other sub-directories of 'bin')?

Current code:

```
find . -name '*.php' \
-and ! -path './bin/*' \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

```
find . \( \! -iregex ^./bin/.\* -o -iregex ^./include/something/.\* \) \
    -name \*.php
```

Comment: No - but I've rewrote the question so hopefully I'm explaining myself better now.

Comment: yoavf, so I've edited my reply

Answer (score 3):

```
find /bin /bin/php -maxdepth 1 -name "*.php"
```

#### Proof of concept

```
$ tree /bin
/bin
|-- ash
|-- dont_search
|   |-- hide_me.php
|   `-- hide_me.txt
|-- du
|-- file.php
|-- fmt
|-- php
|   |-- hide_me.txt
|   `-- show_me.php
`-- zsh

2 directories, 184 files
```

#### Result

```
$ find /bin /bin/php -maxdepth 1 -name "*.php"
/bin/file.php
/bin/php/show_me.php
```

Notice that ***/bin/dont_search/hide_me.php*** did not match

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . ./bin/php -path ./bin -prune -o -print
```

This will ignore files that are within ./bin, too, though.

By the way, it's "find" rather than "Bash find".

Answer (score 1):

GNU find

```
find . -name "*.txt" ! -iregex ".*/bin/.*"
```